# How to autoplay the slider of alvarotrigo/fullPage.js?

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I have to autoplay the slider of fullpage.js, But i can't find how to do that. Any one can help me. I have a 3 slider and it have to slide auto continuously.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/532) and at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2dhkR/119/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3'],
        afterRender: function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fullpage.js has no built-in function for automatic slideshows. However I was involved in creating a website with the same wish like you.

You need to create a function which uses `setInterval` in combination with `$.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight()` from fullpage.js.

Here is a nice example I created for you: http://codepen.io/edgarklepek42/pen/KVKpZb

Right now it changes every 2 seconds. Feel free to adjust it to your liking.

I hope you got the idea.